# Unable to display static text from static resource in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources

I am trying to retreive the text in LWC from a text file which I uploaded on static resource.

```
    import textfromStatic from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Level_1';

    textfromStatic = textfromStatic;
```

Template looks like below :-

```
 <div>
                    <p>text from static resource<lightning-formatted-text name="Typethis" value={textfromStatic}></lightning-formatted-text></p>

                </div>
```

Output am receiving is below:-

```
static resource/resource/1610618314000/AnkushTest__Level_1
```

Comment: what is the content type of your static resource

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. Importing a static resource just imports a URL you can use to get the data. You need to still actually load the data somehow. At a very basic level, something like this should work:

```
this.staticResourceText = await fetch(textfromStatic, { credentials: 'include' });
```