# static resource is not visible

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, formula-field, custom-field, static-resources

I have a field named Statut__c , it is a picklist ( Active / Inactive ) , i want to get a static ressource named Inactif if the value is Inactive and Actif is the value is Active .

i DID get any result , the static ressource don't appear ,like if it don't exist

My code is below :

JS

```
import STATUT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Station_status__c';
import Actif from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Actif'; 
import Inactif from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Inactif';
import AccountStatut  from '@salesforce/apex/MyController.AccountStatut';
// i added this line based on the proposition 
import { getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';


export default class Station extends LightningElement {
  Actif = Actif ;
  Inactif = Inactif ;
  @track icon ;
    connectedCallback(){
      AccountStatut().then(data=>
          {
            switch(getFieldValue(data, STATUT_FIELD)) {
case 'Inactive': 
  this.icon = Inactif
  break
case 'Active':
  this.icon = Actif
  break
}
          })
```

Html

```
  <div>
  <img src={statut_icon}> </div>
```

Apex

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Account AccountStatut(Id AccountId){
        return [SELECT Id,  Station_status__c, FROM Account 
         WHERE Id=:AccountId LIMIT 1];
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/368332/edit) your question to add information as to what you mean by "not visible": Are you getting an error? (If so, add *exact* error text.) Are you gettting "weird" results? (If so, don't say "weird", but explain exactly what you are seeing.) Etc.

Comment: @Moonpie thank you , i just modified my question

Comment: I think the answer to the following question will help you: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/337115/81648

Comment: Please do not change the code that you initially posted to what was suggested in an answer. That will confuse potential future readers who are trying to follow the progression of your original question on through to the answer. You can accept an answer (which you did - thanks!), and/or you can comment on an answer. If you do want to update your original question to indicate that you tried something given in a comment or an answer, instead of changing your original code, please add it at the bottom of your question. Many people put **UPDATE** at the bottom and then what they tried below that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing the field incorrectly. You should use [getFieldValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_value).

```
import { getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'
```

...

```
switch(getFieldValue(data, STATUT_FIELD)) {
  case 'Inactive': 
    this.icon = Inactif
    break
  case 'Active':
    this.icon = Actif
    break
}
```

You could also use the value directly:

```
switch(data[STATUT_FIELD.fieldApiName]) {
```

The `[]` operator accesses a property on an object dynamically.

Comment: thank you for your help , but in my code i already use `    @wire(AccountStatut,{ AccountId: '$recordId'}) account;
 get Statut__c (){
     return this.account.data  ? getSObjectValue(this.account.data, STATUT_FIELD ) : '';
    }` How can i use your code proposition

Comment: @marysnh this code: `if(data.STATUT_FIELD== 'Inactive'){` is incorrect, you need to use getFieldValue there instead.

Comment: i have tried your solution , but i don't now what i have wrong because the image is not visible , i will modified in my first code , if you can help me , i will be very thankful